# How to pass on data from inside a function to different class in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As a Flutter beginner I'm trying to build a calendar app in which I want to fetch data from a specific day from the Firestore database. Right now there's an _onDaySelected function which prints the selected day from the calendar in the flutter console like this 'flutter: 2019-11-04'. I would like this String to be passed on to the MessagesStream class so I can call .document('$currentDay') instead of hardcoding the day like this: .document('2019-11-04'). I have included the code below.

Would anyone know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

```
class RoosterTest extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _RoosterTestState createState() => _RoosterTestState();
}

class _RoosterTestState extends State<RoosterTest>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();

  String messageText;

  static final now = DateTime.now();
  static final formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  static final formatted = formatter.format(now);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _events = {};

    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];

    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    String currentDay = formatter.format(day).toString();
    print('$currentDay');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildTableCalendar(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          MessagesStream(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedColor: Colors.red,
        todayColor: Colors.blue,
        markersColor: Colors.green,
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }
```

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('days')
          .document('2019-11-04')
          .collection('hours')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          );

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of the `_onDaySelected` method in a variable on your state class:

```dart
class _RoosterTestState extends State<RoosterTest>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    String stringOfSelectedDay='defaultValue';
[...]
```

Don't forget in your first time opening the app you should provide `stringOfSelectedDay` with a default value. What should your `MessagesStream` return when the _onDaySelected hasn't been called yet? Maybe today's date?

So, on the method you can store it like:

```dart
void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    String currentDay = formatter.format(day).toString();
    setState(() { 
        stringOfSelectedDay = currentDay; 
    });
    print('$currentDay');
  }
```

You must use setState to make the MessagesStream rebuild itself after the day has changed.

After that, you must make your MessagesStream class have a final variable to make it build the stream based on it, and a constructor that gives it its value:

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  final String date;
  MessagesStream(this.date); //Constructor
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('days')
          .document(date) // Using the final variable here
          .collection('hours')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          );

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }
```

Since you used `setState` this Widget will reflect different calls of the `_onDaySelected` method.

Lastly, when you call your Widget to be constructed, pass the variable accordingly:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildTableCalendar(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          MessagesStream(stringOfSelectedDay), //Using the new constructor you've made.
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```